# Google calendars not displaying with Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to display multiple Google calendars with Full Calendar, like so:

```
eventSources: [
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'a.calendar.google.com'
    },
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'b@group.calendar.google.com'
    },
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'c@group.calendar.google.com'
    }
]
```

All three calendars have the same settings and when I view the calendar at https://www.google.com/calendar/embed… I can see events from the different calendars displayed, but when I view my Full Calendar implementation, I can only see events from one of the calendars.

If I comment out the source of the calendar with events, my calendar shows no events.

Do I need to set up different API keys for each calendar? I haven't done anything that specifically ties the calendar that is working to the API key I've set up so far.

Comment: Each calendar should have its own API key. check this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: I looked at that page and if you look at the example under the 'Multiple Google Calendars' heading, it seems you can use a single API key for multiple calendars. I'll try creating separate keys for each of them though.

Comment: You can access with single key, if the calendars are shared with each other. other wise you cannot as you dont have access to do so..

Comment: If by 'shared with each other' you mean they all appear on the same calendar when viewed in Google (i.e. they appear in the left column for editing), then yes, they're all on the same calendar.